# Team Foundation Build 2010 - Label builds with shelvesets

Tags: label, tfsbuild

How can I label builds with in Team Foundation Build 2010? If I have a shelveset with a new file (added file), applying a label fails with the following error:

> Unable to apply label (p)
>   LABEL to item $/NEWITEM
>   because this item has not yet been
>   checked in. Check in this item and
>   then try again.

Answer (score 0):

If something's in a shelveset it hasn't necessarily been checked in yet, it's just been 'shelved' until a later date.  If you want to label it you actually have to check it in (then it'll be part of a changeset).